# Taylor series of $\ln(x+2)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I try to determine the Taylor series of $\ln(x+2)$. Since I know $\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$, I suppose I can rewrite,
\begin{align}
\ln(x+2) &= \ln(1-(-(x+1)))=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (x+1)^n}{n} \\
&= - x - 1 + \frac{1}{2}(x+1)^2 - \frac{1}{3}(x+1)^3 + \cdots 
\end{align}

But, I don't know why, I don't get the same result than [wolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20ln%28x%2B2%29).

Comment: @NoChance $1-(-(x+1))=1-(-x-1)=1+x+1=x+2$.

Comment: You are correct about that!

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\ln (x+2)=\ln 2+\ln \left(1+\cfrac x2\right)$ will readily give you the same as wolfram.

If you look carefully at the first of the series representations in the link you provided, you will see that it is the same as your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution gives the Taylor series around $x = -1$, and wolfram gives it around $x = 0$.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+ln%28x%2B2%29+around+x+%3D+-1

Check this out, it is the same as you suggested.

Comment: What modification I have to make to calculate it around $x=0$?

Comment: @hlapointe Well, you can make use of change of variable. You know the Maclaurin series for $ln(1+t)$. So put your original equation in this form, determine your $t$, and write the Maclaurin expansion, and then turn all $t$s into $x$.